# How to bind asp.net grid view using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to bind data into grid view using jquery. data is succesfully loaded in "result" but can not apply this data in grid view

My Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '../_AJAX/ajaxCall-InterestSubsidy.aspx',
            data: { 'MODE': 'BindGrid' },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                var reslk = result;

                $.each(result.Table1, function(index, res) {
                    $(".GridView1").append("<table><tr><td>" + res.StateId +
                    "</td><td>" + res.StateName +
                    "</td></tr></table>");

                });
            },
            error: function(e) {
            }
        });
    });
```

My grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="GridView1">

</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
                $.map(result.d, function (item) {
                    $(".GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + item.StateId +
                "</td><td>" + item.StateName +
                "</td></tr>");

                });
```

or

```
                $.map(result.Table1, function (index, res) {
                    $(".GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + res.StateId +
                "</td><td>" + res.StateName +
                "</td></tr>");

                });
```